Two-dimensional wave equation and Bessel function
Show that the solution $w(x_1,t)$ to the initial-value problem
$\begin{equation}\begin{cases} w_{tt}-c^{2}w_{x_{1}x_{1}}=c^{2}\lambda^{2}w\\ w(x_{1},0)=0, w_{t}(x_{1},0)=g(x_1)=\psi(x_1) \end{cases}\end{equation}$ is given by $w(x_1,t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_{1}-ct}^{x_{1}+ct}J_{0}(\lambda s)\psi(y_{1})dy_{1}.$
Here $s=c^2t^2-(x_1-y_1)^2$, while $J_{0}(z)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos( z\sin \theta)~d\theta.$
I am trying to solve the exercise, there is a suggestion:
Define $u(x_1,x_2,t):=\cos(\lambda x_2)w(x_1,t)$ and use the two-dimensional equation satisfied by $u$, this is
$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\text{Vol}(B{(x,t)})}\int_{B(x,t)}\frac{tg(y)+t^{2}h(y)+tDg(y)\cdot(y-x)}{(t^{2}-|y-x|^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}dy,$ where $\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} u_{tt}-\Delta u=0 \text{ in }\mathbb{R}^{n}\times(0,\infty)\\ u=g,u_{t}=h,  \text{ in }\mathbb{R}^{n}\times \{t=0\}.
\end{cases}\end{equation}$.
I appreciate any suggestion or possible solution.

One likely typo: I suspect $s^2=c^2 t^2-(x_1-y_1)^2$. ($\lambda$ must have dimensions of length$^{-1}$, so if $s=c^2 t^2-(x_1-y_1)^2$ then $s$ has dimensions of length$^{2}$. But then $\lambda s$ is not dimensionless, which it should be to enter as the argument of $J_0(z)$.)

I can at least clarify how to get started with the hint.
First, if we rescale $t\to t/c$ then the PDE can be simplified to $w_{tt}-w_{x_1 x_1}=\lambda^2 w$. So we can assume $c=1$ without loss of generality and restore it at the end. With this in mind, we consider the hint and write $u(x_1,x_2,t)=\cos(x_2 \lambda)w(x_1,t)$. Then
$$u_{tt}-\Delta u=\cos(x_2\lambda)(w_{tt}-w_{x_1x_1}-\lambda^2 w)$$
So if $w(x_1,t)$ satisfies its PDE then $u$ also satisfies its own PDE. Moreover, we have
\begin{align}
u(x_1,x_2,0)&=\cos(x_2\lambda)w(x_1,0)=0,\\
u_t(x_1,x_2,0)&=\cos(x_2\lambda)w_t(x_1,0)=\cos(x_2 \lambda)\psi(x_1)
\end{align}
Hence $g(x_1,x_2,t)=0$ and $h(x_1,x_2,t)=\cos(x_2\lambda) \psi(x_1)$. It therefore suffices to write down to write out the 2D solution formula for $u(x_1,x_2,t)$ and solve for $w(x_1,t)$. What remains is to show that this is equivalent to the result.

thanks so much @semiclassical

$u(x_1,x_2;t)=\frac{1}{2\pi t^2}\int_{B(x,t)}\frac{t^2cos(\lambda y_2)\psi(y_1)}{(t^2-|y-x|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}dy$, Can you tell me how I can integrate that expression?

@logarithm You can parametrize the disk of radius $t$ at $x=(x_1,x_2)$ in Cartesian coordinates $y=(y_1,y_2)$ in the usual way. The challenge is to compute the inner $y_2$ integral, and it helps to isolate the even part of said integral.

Thank you very much for your suggestion.
